# Why is this apple script opening safari as hidden?

Tags: macos, safari, applescript

I am working on building a more complex applescript but I wanted to get the basics working first.

```
tell application "Safari"
activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        tell menu bar 1
            tell menu bar item "File"
                tell menu "File"
                    click menu item "New Window"
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

The problem I cant seem to figure out is why when I run it, safari is opened as hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new windows are not hidden when I run your script.

Try this:

```
tell application "Safari" to make new document
```

Comment: with that and moving the activate command to the end, it works now thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It didn't open Safari hidden for me either, but Safari opened behind other applications if it wasn't already running until I added `set frontmost to true` to the end.

```
activate application "Safari"
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
    click menu item "New Window" of menu 1 of menu bar item 3 of menu bar 1
    set frontmost to true
end tell
```

You could also try using `reopen`. It opens a new default window if there are no visible windows or if only for example a preferences window is visible, or if all default windows are minimized, it unminimizes one of them.

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    reopen
end tell
```

Comment: I was able to solve my problem using a different method but these suggestions are good